# Data Set and Primary Key

Tags: c#

my Table `Kategorija` has Primary Key (`IDKategorije`)

When I use a data set, like in a part of my code:

```
string s = textBox1.Text ;
DataRow dRow2 = ds1.Tables["Kategorija"].Rows.Find(s);
```

I get an error :

> Table has no Primary Key

How is that?

Answer (score 2):

That is, because your `DataTable` has no primary key defined.  This has nothing to do with the Table in your database, but I guess that the `Find` method on the `Rows` collection needs a primary key constraint on the `DataTable` in order to work.

More information regarding the `PrimaryKey` property can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx)

Next to that, I think you're better of using a [Typed Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can only use DataTable.Rows.Find() if you defined a primary key for that DataTable. Take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the PrimaryKey property on the DataTable first.  See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk.aspx